# Read file in directory Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia, listdir

How can I get list of files of directory in Aurelia? 
I have relative path to resources which I want to list.

Require('fs') does not work in Aurelia. What else can I do?

Comment: `require(fs)` does not work in Aurelia because that is node-only.  If you are building an Electron or other native app that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant. My suggestion would be to make an api call that returns you a list of available files.

Comment: Can you give me any link or example of how to do that?